# Aligning the table to the top of the page

Tags: css, html-table, kendo-grid

Here is the plunk below, I'm trying to push the internal table to the top of the page tried different CSS but it doesn't get aligned to the top.

```
<td width="30%">
        <div>
          <h4>Category properties</h4>
          <table style=>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Name
              </td>
              <td>
                {{selectedCategory.name}}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Source</td>
              <td>{{selectedCategory.source}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Tenancy</td>
              <td>{{selectedCategory.tenancy}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Display Name</td>
              <td>{{selectedCategory.displayName}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/C4vDxt09kmLPUPQNssL4?p=preview

Comment: have you tried z-index?

Comment: What do you mean by "internal"?